# iPhone - How to return year as an integer from a given date?

Tags: iphone, nsdate, nscalendar

I'm trying to return the 4 digit year from any given date as an integer.  I'm not strong with the NSCalendar or NSDate functions, but have tried using them with components from date and date formatters with no success.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `NSCalendar` [docs](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCalendar/components:fromDate:):

```
unsigned unitFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit;
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *comps = [gregorian components:unitFlags fromDate:date];
```

Then you can get the year by doing:

```
NSInteger year = [comps year];
```

Comment: Thank you - that did it.  The last line is what I had been missing; I didn't know how to reference the year specifically.